# backpack for laravel: is there something that helps inserting data into a pivot table?

Tags: laravel-backpack

- I've `customers` table
- I've `orders` table
- I've a `customer_order` pivot table

.. but pivot table has additional columns

So I must allow admin to edit additional data into the pivot table.

Is there something in laravel-backpack that allows this kind of editing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backpack 4.2 (due this next week) includes that exact feature. See [the docs for it](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.2-dev/crud-fields#save-additional-data-to-pivot-table).

In Backpack 4.1 there is not, but you can add a `repeatable` field, then manually save the contents of that `repeatable` on the pivot table.

Comment: Thanks we folled the json getter way and modified store and update to handle it and validate json fields. I'm happy anyway. And I can't wait for v4.2. Backpack is absolutely one of best thing I discovered in the php / laravel world